# Declaring Angular service with new instance

Tags: angularjs

I guess its pretty newbie question, but I cant figure it out myself.
I am struggling with creating an angular service which will allow me to initiate an Object once with initial values and then other controllers would be able to use this instance.
Currently, the getter/setter are not working. Plus, controller2 is being called before the object is created.

How should I write this service in proper way?

Page (base) Controller:

```
vm.user = userService.createNewUser(data); /// init with data
```

Sub Page Controller1:

```
vm.user.userInfo = userService.getUserInfo(); /// getter
```

Sub Page Controller2:

```
userService.setUserInfo(data); /// setter
```

Service:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.user')
        .factory('userService', userService);

    function userService() {
        return {
            createNewUser: function (data) {  /// init only once
                return new User(data);
            },
            getUserInfo: function () {
                return User.getUserInfo();
            },
            setUserInfo: function (customer) {
                return User.setUserInfo(customer);
            }
        };



    function User(data) { /// ctor
                this.XXXX = {
                user_code: data.customer.user_code,
                user_password: data.customer.user_password
                };
                this.YYYY = {
                //// some vars
               }

        User.prototype = {
            getXXXXUserInfo: function () {
                return this.XXXX;
            },
            setXXXXUserInfo: function (customer) {
                this.XXXX.user_code = customer.user_code;
                this.XXXX.user_password = customer.user_password;
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function userService() {
    return {
        user:null,
        createNewUser: function (data) {  /// init only once
           // check for null here if you don't want to be able to only more than once
           this.user = new User(data);

        },
        getUserInfo: function () {
            this.user.getUserInfo();
        },
        setUserInfo: function (customer) {
            this.user.setUserInfo(customer);
            // i removed the return since User.setUserInfo is nt returning anything 

        }
    };



function User(data) { /// ctor
            this.XXXX = {
            user_code: data.customer.user_code,
            user_password: data.customer.user_password
            };
            this.YYYY = {
            //// some vars
           }

    User.prototype = {
        getXXXXUserInfo: function () {
            return this.XXXX;
        },
        setXXXXUserInfo: function (customer) {
            this.XXXX.user_code = customer.user_code;
            this.XXXX.user_password = customer.user_password;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: It appears that getUserInfo is called before object is created (createNewUser). How do I control this?

Comment: the best would be to have vm.user = userService.createNewUser(data); /// init with data in an angular.run bloc. angular;run will ge executed only once and before any controller.

Comment: will check this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you `return` an instance of `User`. You need to save the user instance in the service first, and then return it.

```
angular
    .module('app.user')
    .factory('userService', userService);

function userService() {
    var user; // prepare space in the service for the user instance

    return {
        createNewUser: function (data) {  
            return user = new User(data); // user is now saved in the userService service
        },
        ...
    };

    ....
```

Comment: Thank you, but now I cant test it as controller2 is called before the object is created. How do I change the order?

Comment: see the updated answer. If you want to share data between multiple controllers, you have to have the user object above the return statement